# Runtime Analysis of Insertion Sort

Tags: algorithm, sorting, insertion

I am trying to compute the run-time analysis of this Insertion Sort algorithm:

```
1) n = length[A]
2) count = 0
3) for (i=1; i<=n; i++)
4)     for (j=1; j<=i; j++)
5)         if A[j] <= 100
6)              for (k=j; k<=j+2*i; k++)
7)                  A[j] = A[j]-1
8)                  count = count+1
9) return (count)
```

I have watched some videoes on youtube like: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tmKUHLs21PU 
I have also read by book and I cannot find anything online that is similair to this (because of the 3 nested for loops and and if statement).

Now I am pretty good up until about like 5.

I understand that the runtime for line 3 is **n**, and for 4 it is **Σ j =1 to n (tj)**

after that I am completely lost, I know that there are to 'Σ's involved with the if statement and 3rd for loop. Can somebody please explain in detail what to do next and why it is like that. Thank you.

Comment: Indent the code please.

Comment: Are you calculating asymptotic complexity with Big-O notation?

Comment: Pretty much, I need to find the best and worst case @StriplingWarrior

Answer (score 0):

This sounds a lot like a homework problem, and it wouldn't be doing you any favors to just give you all the answers, but here are some principles that can hopefully help you figure out the rest on your own.

Line 4 will happen once the first time through the outer loop, twice the second time, and so forth up to `n` times on the nth time through the loop.

```
1 + 2 + ... + n
```

If we rearrange these to put the first and last addend together, then the second and the second-to-last, we see a pattern:

```
1 + 2 + ... (n-1) + n 
= (n + 1) + (n - 1 + 2) + ... + (n - n/2 + n/2 + 1)
= (n + 1) + (n + 1) + ... + (n + 1)
= (n + 1) * n/2
= n²/2 + n/2
```

In terms of asymptotic complexity, the constant `1/2` and the `n` are outweighed by the `n²`, so the big-O of line 4 is `n²`.

Line 5 will have to be evaluated as many times as line 4 runs, regardless of what it evaluates to, so that'll be `n²`. But how many times the lines inside it are run will depend on the values in the array. This is where you start running into best-case and worst-case complexity.

In the best case, the value in the array will always be greater than 100, so the complexity of the entire algorithm is equal to the complexity of line 5.

In the worst case, the value in `A[j]` will always be less than or equal to 100, so the `for` loop on line 6 will be evaluated, increasing the complexity of the overall algorithm.

I'll leave you to figure out how the remaining lines will affect the overall complexity.

And by the way, this doesn't look like an insertion sort to me. It's not comparing array values to each other and swapping their positions in an array. It's comparing array values to a constant (`100`) and reducing their values based on their position in the array.